# scrapy returns "Response content isn't text" while trying to donload an image

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to download images with scrapy which return the following error:

```
raise NotSupported("Response content isn't text")
scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported: Response content isn't text
2018-11-30 14:36:09 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.example.bla/39307b2103.jpg>
```

This is the coresponding code I am using:

```
...
myitem['i10_img']       = 'https://www.example.de' + response.css("#fullscreen_img::attr(src)").extract_first()[2:]
yield scrapy.Request(myitem['i10_img'],callback=self.parseImages,  meta={'item': myitem})

return myitem

def parseImages(self, response):
    for elem in response.xpath("//img"):
        img_url = elem.xpath("@src").extract_first()
        yield ImageItem(image_urls=[img_url])
```

items.py

```
class ImageItem(scrapy.Item):
image_urls = scrapy.Field()
images = scrapy.Field()
```

Is there something I need to adapt within the yield command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how the images pipeline works.
You're trying to create a request to the image url itself and parse that as HTML.

Instead, you should simply add the image url to `image_urls` of `myitem` (like you're trying to do in `parseImages`).

Comment: I don't understand. How would scrapy know what to take (the img or the txt)? myitem['i10_img']  contains the URL already and the image folder is empty.

Comment: Scrapy's images pipeline will (by default) download images from urls inside the `image_urls` list. It won't even look at some random `i10_img` field. So if you store the url in `myitem['i10_img']`, you only get the url, if you store it in `myitem['image_urls']`, the image will also be downloaded.